# createMaterialTopTabNavigator inside a CardView?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation, tabnavigator, react-native-tabnavigator

how can place createMaterialTopTabNavigator inside a CardView?

I want to achieve the design shown in the below screenshot

[image]

I am not understanding where should i write the createMaterialTopTabNavigator, should i write it in the same page or should i write it in the RootScreen (Where multiple navigators are present eg: StackNavigator and BottomTabNavigator)

how should i go about creating this?

Comment: I have solved it see answer below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created a createMaterialTopTabNavigator in the same page where i wanted to add a tab component

```
const HistoryTabs = (
  {
    UPoints: {
      screen: UPointsScreen,     
    },
    MyPurchases: {
      screen: MyPurchasesScreen,     
    },

  },
  {initialRouteName:'UPoints' }

);
const AppContainer = createAppContainer(HistoryTabs);
```

and in render i called

```
 <View style={{flex:1}}>
      <AppContainer/>
 </View>
```